# Error deploying mdapi to packaging org with a namespace

Tags: salesforcedx, packaging, mdapi

I had a SFDX project which I converted to follow the "[sfdx-falcon-template](https://github.com/sfdx-isv/sfdx-falcon-template)" structure. I also created a packaging org that would be used as a base for my managed package.

Next I created a namespace and a managed package and updated my "sfdx-project.json" file according to sfdx-falcon-template:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    { "path": "sfdx-source/<my-namespace>", "default": true },
    { "path": "sfdx-source/unpackaged"},
    { "path": "sfdx-source/untracked"}
  ],
  "namespace": "<my-namespace>",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "42.0"
}
```

I use `<my-namespace>` as an example here, I don't want to expose the real name.

Then I issued the `./dev-tools/rebuild-scratch-org` command in command line which basically created a new scratch org and deployed all the metadata and code there. The command ran successfully and I ran all the tests to verify nothing got broken. Everything was fine so far.

But when I tried to deploy my application to my packagking org, it failed:

```
=== Result
Status:  Failed
jobid:  0Af1t000002pL79CAE
Completed:  2018-07-23T14:25:44.000Z
Component errors:  438
Components deployed:  91
Components total:  529
Tests errors:  0
Tests completed:  0
Tests total:  0
Check only: false
```

This is weird and seems that something wrong with a namespace. Does anybody know how to fix this and deploy my app into the package org eventually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what issue was. I have 2 custom objects with `<startsWith>Vowel</startsWith>` in their metadata definition. And in a long log of errors I found this line:

> Cannot specify a startsWith attribute for this language

When I removed `<startsWith>Vowel</startsWith>` from objects' metadata definition, deployment finished successfully.

P.S. This is odd that this object setting didn't allow deploying mdapi to packaging org with a namespace, but it deployed to a scratch org smoothly. That's ridiculous, I'm confused.